# Product Spinner slow on mobile

Tags: vue.js

i'm struggling to see where my script is slowing down on mobile devices. If you click and drag on the image it will rotate, do the same on mobile and it is really slow!

I have moved the script to it's own page, unable to add it here as AJAX requests don't seem to work and there is a large array of images that is pulled in.

My issue simply is moving doesn't move in time with your finger...

http://click.martynleeball.co.uk/360/

This is the script:

```js
Vue.component('viewer', {
    data() {
        return {
            loading: false,

            loop: true,
            speed: 2,
            reverse: true,

            speedController: 0,

            zoomEnabled: true,
            zoomLevels: [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3],
            zoomLevel: 1,

            frame: 1,
            images: [],
            imagesPreloaded: 0,

            spinEnabled: true,
            spinAuto: false,

            viewportScale: 0.3,
            viewportEnabled: true,
            viewportOpacity: 0.8,

            lastX: 0,
            lastY: 0,

            startX: 0,
            startY: 0,

            translateX: 0,
            translateY: 0,

            isMoving: false,
            isDragging: false,

            lastPinch: 0,

            animationRequestID: 0,

            spinStart: null,
            spinThen: Date.now(),
            fps: 1000 / 8,

            $moveEvent: null
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleEnd);
        window.addEventListener('touchend', this.handleEnd);
        window.addEventListener('orientationchange', this.fetch);

        // iOS Specific
        this.$el.addEventListener('gesturestart', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        this.fetch();
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        window.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.handleEnd);
        window.removeEventListener('touchend', this.handleEnd);
    },
    methods: {
        fetch: function () {
            
            const self = this;

            // Reset the preload
            this.imagesPreloaded = 0;
            this.loading = true;

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                    // All of the 360 images.
                    self.images = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    
                    var images = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < self.images.length; i++) {
                        images[i] = new Image();
                        images[i].src = self.images[i][1].url;
                        
                        self.imagesPreloaded++;
                    }

                    // Some dealers spin the vehicle the wrong way...
                    if (self.reverse) {
                        self.images = self.images.reverse();
                    }
                    
                    self.loading = false;
                    
                    if (self.spinAuto && self.spinEnabled) {
                        self.spinStart = self.spinThen;
                        self.spin(1);
                    }
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "./images.php", true);
            xhttp.send();
        },
        handleStart($event) {
            if ($event.button && $event.button !== 0) {
                return;
            }
            if (this.animationRequestID !== 0) {
                this.spinStop();
            }
            this.isMoving = true;
            this.isDragging = true;

            this.startX = $event.pageX || $event.touches[0].pageX;
            this.startY = $event.pageY || $event.touches[0].pageY;
        },
        handleMove($event, viewport) {
            if ($event.button && $event.button !== 0) {
                return;
            }
            if ($event.touches && $event.touches.length > 1) {
                this.zoomPinch($event);
                return;
            }

            this.$moveEvent = $event;

            if (this.isMoving && this.isDragging) {
                const positions = {
                    x: $event.pageX || $event.touches[0].pageX,
                    y: $event.pageY || $event.touches[0].pageY
                }

                if (this.zoomLevel !== 1) {
                    this.translate(positions, null, viewport);
                }
                if (this.zoomLevel === 1) {
                    this.changeFrame(positions, $event.touches && $event.touches.length >= 1);
                }

                this.lastX = positions.x;
                this.lastY = positions.y;
            }
        },
        handleEnd: function () {
            this.lastPinch = 0;
            this.isMoving = false;
        },

        spin(index) {
            let i = index;
            if (i >= this.images.length) {
                i = 1;
            }
            this.animationRequestID = window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.spin(i));

            let now = Date.now();
            let elapsed = now - this.spinThen;

            if (elapsed > this.fps) {
                this.spinThen = now - (elapsed % this.fps);
                this.frame = i;
                i += 1;
            }
        },
        spinToggle: function () {
            if (this.animationRequestID === 0 && this.zoomLevel === 1) {
                this.spin(this.frame);
                return;
            }
            this.spinStop();
        },
        spinStop: function () {
            if (this.animationRequestID) {
                window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationRequestID);
                this.animationRequestID = 0;
            }
        },

        translate(positions, zooming, viewport) {
            if (this.$moveEvent) {
                this.$moveEvent.preventDefault();
            }
            window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                positions = positions || {
                    x: this.startX,
                    y: this.startY
                };

                if (viewport) {
                    this._translateFromViewport(positions);
                } else {
                    this._translateFromImage(positions, zooming);
                }

                this.startX = positions.x;
                this.startY = positions.y;
            });
        },

        /**
         * @param positions
         * @private
         */
        _translateFromViewport(positions) {
            let move = {
                x: Math.floor(positions.x - this.startX),
                y: Math.floor(positions.y - this.startY)
            };

            let box = this.$refs.viewportBox.getBoundingClientRect();
            let container = this.$refs.viewportContainer.getBoundingClientRect();

            // Amount of pixels moved within animation frame, adjust based on viewport scale.
            // Zoom level doesn't matter as image scale doesn't move, so box is moving same amount of pixels.
            let moveAmountX = (move.x / this.viewportScale);
            let moveAmountY = (move.y / this.viewportScale);

            // Find the current offset of the container bounds, calculate new offset based on movement amount
            let calculatedOffset = {
                left: (container.left - box.left) - moveAmountX,
                right: (container.right - box.right) - moveAmountX,
                top: (container.top - box.top) - moveAmountY,
                bottom: (container.bottom - box.bottom) - moveAmountY
            };

            // Only move if the calculated new offset is not out of container bounds
            // Reverse the movement as moving box in same direction as cursor rather than the image.
            if (calculatedOffset.left <= 0 && calculatedOffset.right >= 0) {
                this.translateX += -moveAmountX;
            }
            if (calculatedOffset.top <= 0 && calculatedOffset.bottom >= 0) {
                this.translateY += -moveAmountY;
            }

        },
        _translateFromImage(positions, zooming) {
            let move = {
                x: Math.floor(positions.x - this.startX),
                y: Math.floor(positions.y - this.startY)
            };

            let image = this.$refs.image.getBoundingClientRect();
            let container = this.$refs.container.getBoundingClientRect();

            let moveAmountX = move.x * this.zoomLevel;
            let moveAmountY = move.y * this.zoomLevel;

            let calculatedOffset = {
                left: (container.left - image.left) - moveAmountX,
                right: (container.right - image.right) - moveAmountX,
                top: (container.top - image.top) - moveAmountY,
                bottom: (container.bottom - image.bottom) - moveAmountY
            };

            if (zooming) {
                if (calculatedOffset.left <= 0) {
                    this.translateX += calculatedOffset.left;
                }
                if (calculatedOffset.right >= 0) {
                    this.translateX += calculatedOffset.right;
                }
                if (calculatedOffset.top <= 0) {
                    this.translateY += calculatedOffset.top;
                }
                if (calculatedOffset.bottom >= 0) {
                    this.translateY += calculatedOffset.bottom;
                }
            }

            if (calculatedOffset.left >= 0 && calculatedOffset.right <= 0) {
                this.translateX += move.x / this.zoomLevel;
            }

            if (calculatedOffset.top >= 0 && calculatedOffset.bottom <= 0) {
                this.translateY += move.y / this.zoomLevel;
            }
        },

        changeFrame(positions, touch) {
            this.speedController += 1;
            if ((this.speedController < this.speed) && !touch) {
                return;
            }
            if (this.speedController > this.speed) {
                this.speedController = 0;
            }

            if (positions.x > this.lastX) {
                if (this.frame >= 0 && this.frame < this.images.length) {
                    this.frame += 1;
                } else if (this.loop) {
                    this.frame = 1;
                }
            } else if (positions.x < this.lastX) {
                if (this.frame >= 0 && this.frame - 1 > 0) {
                    this.frame -= 1;
                } else if (this.loop) {
                    this.frame = this.images.length;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        zoomLevel: function () {
            if (this.zoomLevel !== 1 && this.animationRequestID !== 0) {
                this.spinStop();
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        closestZoom: function () {
            return this.zoomLevels.reduce((a, b) => {
                return Math.abs(b - this.zoomLevel) < Math.abs(a - this.zoomLevel) ? b : a;
            });
        },
        imageSet: function () {
            return this.images.map(image => {
                return image[this.closestZoom].url;
            });
        },
        preloadProgress: function () {
            return Math.floor(this.imagesPreloaded / this.images.length * 100);
        },
        currentPath: function () {
            return this.images[this.frame - 1][this.closestZoom].url;
        },
        nextZoomLevel: function () {
            if (this.zoomLevels.indexOf(this.closestZoom) === this.zoomLevels.length - 1) {
                return this.zoomLevels[0];
            }
            return this.zoomLevels[this.zoomLevels.indexOf(this.closestZoom) + 1];
        },
        viewportTransform: function () {
            if (this.viewportEnabled) {
                let translateX = -((this.translateX * this.viewportScale) * this.zoomLevel);
                let translateY = -((this.translateY * this.viewportScale) * this.zoomLevel);

                return `scale(${1 / this.zoomLevel}) translateX(${translateX}px) translateY(${translateY}px)`;
            }
        },
        transform: function () {
            return `scale(${this.zoomLevel}) translateX(${this.translateX}px) translateY(${this.translateY}px)`;
        },
        canZoomIn: function () {
            return this.zoomLevels[this.zoomLevels.indexOf(this.closestZoom) + 1] === undefined
        },
        canZoomOut: function () {
            return this.zoomLevels[this.zoomLevels.indexOf(this.closestZoom) + -1] === undefined
        }
    },
    template: '#template'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the answer, turns on a mobile browser update has given scrolling a higher priority than other touch events, so adding `touch-action: none;` to my image fixes this issue!